# kmltree not looking right

Tags: kml

I am trying to get kmltree to work.  The kmz is being loaded but the tree will not expand to show child elements.  Also he proper folder icons do not appear.  May be related?
Anyone see what I might be doing wrong?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Simple Example</title>
        <script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi?key=ABCD"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!-- earth-api-utility-library dependencies -->
        <script src="http://geojs.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/dist/geo.pack.js"></script>
        <script src="http://earth-api-utility-library.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/extensions/dist/extensions.pack.js">
        </script>
        <!-- kmltree source files -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../dist/kmltree.css" media="screen">
        <script src="../dist/kmltree.min.js"></script>

        <script>
            google.load("earth", "1");

            function init() {
                google.earth.createInstance('map3d', initCB, failureCB);
            }

            function initCB(instance) {
                ge = instance;
                ge.getWindow().setVisibility(true);

                var gex = gex = new GEarthExtensions(ge);

                var tree = kmltree({
                    url: 'http://kmltree.googlecode.com/hg/examples/kml/hello.kml',
                    gex: gex, 
                    mapElement: $('#map3d'), 
                    element: $('#tree'),
                });

                tree.load();
            }

            function failureCB(errorCode) {
                alert('failed to load plugin');
            }

            $(document).ready(init);

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="tree" style="float:left; width:300px; height: 400px;"></div>
        <div id="map3d" style="float:left; height: 400px; width: 600px;"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just run into the same problem and solved it by adapting the path of all "images/.." links in the "kmltree.css" file to my actual folder setup, e.g. if you place both the original "images" and "css" folder in the root directory you have to change the path to "../images..".